# Naming the class of named objects in the universe of discourse

Tags: logic, terminology

The universe of discourse of a given discussion, treatise, or discourse, is the usually-limited class of individuals under discussion, whose existence is presupposed by the discussants, and which in some sense constitute the ultimate subject matter of the discussion—as explicitly stated by George Boole in 1854. Once the universe of a discourse has been established, expressions such as ‘every object’ and ‘some object’ refer respectively to every object in the universe of discourse and to some object in the universe of discourse.
In the universe [sc. of discourse] of a number theory every object has a name: 0, (0+1), ((0+1) + 1), etc. In the universe of geometry none of the objects have names, as Tarski famously remarked. In the universe of certain set theories countably many objects have names made of brackets: {} is the null set, {{}} is singleton of the null set, {{}{{}}} is doubleton of the null set and the singleton of the null set. But uncountably many objects do not have names.

Frango Nabrasa calls the class of named objects in a given universe its namiverse. Sometimes he says constiverse, to emphasize that the objects are named by constants.

Question : What terms have been used by logicians for the class of objects in a universe of discourse that have object-language names?

Comment: Most formulations of set theory don't actually include brackets as part of their formal language, so the hereditarily finite sets you mentioned do not actually have names.

Comment: Strictly speaking in the language of set theory you only have the the predicate $\in$. However as in natural language you can define new word,  you can define new symbols in formal language. This is called a conservative expansion by function/predicate symbol. E.g. you can add the following axiom to set theory $y=\emptyset\leftrightarrow \forall x(\neg x\in y)$ and use the constant $\emptyset$. Similarly you can define expressions 0,1,2.. but there are no constants in the basic language.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey, @ Gur Ismael Many thanks for catching my glitch. I fixed it. BTW, what is the standard name for the set names composed of nothing but matched brackets?

Comment: I don't know of a name of those names exactly, but the sets described by those names are the (well-founded) _hereditarily finite sets_. (They are exactly the sets which are finite, and whose elements are finite, and whose elements of elements are finite, and so on.)

Comment: "constiverse" sounds like "constipated universe".

Answer (score 2):

Definability has been the subject of intensive study in mathematical logic. An object $c$ is definable in a model $\mathbf{M}$ iff there is a formula $\phi(x)$ such that, for $a \in M$, $\mathbf{M} \models \phi(a)$ iff $a = c$. (More generally, one talks about definable subsets of the universe $M$ of the model $\mathbf{M}$.)

What you call the named objects are the objects that can be defined by a formula $\phi(x)$ of the form $x = t$, where $t$ term containing no free variables. I think definability has been perceived as the more important notion, so there isn't a standard term for your notion of a named object.

[Aside: I think the addition of the terms "namiverse" and "constiverse" to the English language would be both otiose and odious.]